# I want Ubuntu for my Laptop? Should I Use the PC version?

Tags: laptop

I am not sure if i should use the PC version. I am downloading it anyway.

Comment: It'd be helpful to at least include the model or make of your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

You use the PC Version. Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Use the 13.10 version. If you have 2 GB of RAM or less, select 32bit. If you have 2+ GB RAM, use 64bit.

Comment: Why use the 32bit if less than 2Gb RAM? What reasons are there for this?